# Java reserved words as package name in Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is there any way to configure IntelliJ to allow use of Java reserved words as package name ?
Such as `private` or `public`, as they're allowed in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any reserved word with backticks:

```
package `public` // this is actually unnecessary, as public works fine... in Scala

class `class` {
  def `with`: String = "with"
}
```

If intelliJ forbids you, you can simply create entity under different name and then rename it to something with backticks.

**But please, please, never do it in a production code.** This is fragile, makes it much harder to call your interfaces from Java (even though it might already be pretty hard), sometimes breaks macros, is difficult and annoying to type, and might be confusing to formatters or other tools analyzing your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
IntelliJ doesn't forbid me to create the folder, but doesn't interpret the file as a package.

I will follow your advice to not use them, but if anyone is aware of how to modify IntelliJ configuration on those, do not hesitate to post your answer !